# how to call factory function from another factory in the same module in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have these two factories .
factory one

```
sameRoof.factory('dbService', function (localStorageService, backendupdate) {
    return {
      checkCredentials: function () {
        return localStorageService.get('profile');
      },
      handle_credentials: function (param) {
        if (localStorageService.isSupported) {
          var profile = {id: param.id, name: param.name, gender: param.gender, zone: param.locale};
          localStorageService.set('profile', profile);
          backendupdate.updateRequestData();
        }
      }

    };
  });
```

and factory 2 :

```
sameRoof
  .factory('backendUpdate', function () {
    return {
      updateRequestData: function () {
        alert('requestData')
      }}
  });
```

i am not able to call factory 2 in factory one.
I am getting 
Unknown provider: backendupdateProvider <- backendupdate <- dbService ERROR.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems like you've a typo... Replace `backendupdate` with `backendUpdate` in your dependency injections....

```
 function (localStorageService, backendUpdate) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo in the first factory, this:

```
sameRoof.factory('dbService', function (localStorageService, backendUpdate)
```